# Android - MediaPlayer keep going

Tags: java, android

I've this piece of code in my app

```
 mp.start();

    play=mp.isPlaying();

    while(play)
    {
        play=mp.isPlaying();
    }

    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
```

When I'm debugging (I use a real android device) the log window keep saying something like "V/Mediaplayer: isPlaying: 1". It prints this string also when I close the app. I'm sure that my app exit from the loop after the file is played because it executes all instruction after this part. I also tried to use the OnCompletionListener, but it doesn't work like it supposed to do.

I execute  this code in an AsyncTask, could be this the problem?

Comment: Activity.ondestroy - get the mediaplay thread n stop play, reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That while loop is horrible you don't need it, just use the MediaPlayer callbacks or create your owns

[link of android mediaPlayer official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Next you can't call .start() and then stop() just after that.. maybe this is a test but it could be a problem if it's live code.

OnCompletionListener gives you a callback only at the end of the playback track

For tracking the state of your player you could use an enum and an interface to make your own callback

Comment: I know that it's horrible but I need to wait the end of the execution then I have to send a message through socket. The OnCompletionListener doesn't work as expected. Later I'll do another try and let you know!